# Spring Boot Application Shutting Down as soon as it's started

Tags: java, spring-boot

I used Spring Initializr to initialize a new project. I further added MySQL Driver, Spring Data JPA, Spring Boot Actuator, and Spring Web as project dependencies. Exporting the .zip file, the only thing I did is, changed the *application.properties* file. When I run the application, it starts and stops immediately. Here's the response:

```sh
2020-10-29 14:46:52.414  INFO 150728 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-10-29 14:46:58.679  INFO 150728 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-10-29 14:46:58.705  INFO 150728 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2020-10-29 14:46:58.832 DEBUG 150728 --- [           main] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration@2b6a0ea9] to MetadataBuildingContext [org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuildingContextRootImpl@4dde8976]
2020-10-29 14:46:59.028 DEBUG 150728 --- [           main] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration@2b6a0ea9] to SessionFactoryImpl [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@74b86971]
2020-10-29 14:47:17.727  INFO 150728 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-10-29 14:47:17.737 TRACE 150728 --- [           main] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Handling #sessionFactoryCreated from [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@74b86971] for TypeConfiguration
2020-10-29 14:47:17.739  INFO 150728 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-10-29 14:47:17.892  INFO 150728 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 28.826 seconds (JVM running for 29.63)
2020-10-29 14:47:17.905  INFO 150728 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-10-29 14:47:17.905 TRACE 150728 --- [extShutdownHook] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Handling #sessionFactoryClosed from [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@74b86971] for TypeConfiguration
2020-10-29 14:47:17.906 DEBUG 150728 --- [extShutdownHook] o.h.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope     : Un-scoping TypeConfiguration [org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope@ae36ddd] from SessionFactory [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@74b86971]
2020-10-29 14:47:17.910  INFO 150728 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-10-29 14:47:18.760  INFO 150728 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

and my *application.properties* file:

```sh
server.contextPath=/
server.port=4000

#data-source configurations
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://host:3306/schema?useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# DDL generation
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

#Turn Statistics on
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug
# Show all queries
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

My *pom.xml* file is as follows:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Start Spring boot in debug mode by passing in the VM flag "-Ddebug=true"

Comment: Check jdk version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) to set up your project, you might probably have

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
```

as a parent dependency or a similar version of `spring-boot-starter-parent` which is not yet released on maven central. So I suggest you go to maven central and import the latest release, for me it was:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

And this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

On going through your POM file I noticed two things:

1. Version numbers are not mentioned for the dependencies
2. Milestone and Snapshot repository is mentioned under `<repositories>` and `<pluginRepositories>`

So first thing version number will be needed and if you want to use Milestone then your dependency should look something like this

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<version>2.3.0.M1</version>
```

Here M in version denotes Milestone and as you didn't mention any version I used 2.3.0.M1. Similarly you can get it for other dependency as well from maven repository.
I got this from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.3.0.M1

Also I would recommend you using normal Release version instead of using Milestone. If you use Release then your dependency should look like this.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
```

From here you can choose whichever version you want to use.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web

If the above things don't work then try adding this dependency `spring-boot-starter-parent` https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent

Comment: It worked after updating the *spring-boot-starter-web* dependency.

```xml
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
  </dependency>
```